# gnu make. recompile unchanged files only

Tags: c++, makefile

Help me with makefile, please. I want `make' to recompile only files that have been changed. Here is my makefile:

```
ROOT_DIR= ..
BUILD_TYPE= Release
BUILD_DIR= $(ROOT_DIR)/$(BUILD_TYPE)
O_DIR= $(BUILD_DIR)/obj

TARGETS= ftp_auto_backup sftp_auto_backup

CXX= g++
CXXFLAGS= -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB -O3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0
FTP_LDFLAGS= -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -s -L $(ROOT_DIR)/lib/Release -l:libboost_thread-mgw46-mt-1_49.a -l:libcommon.a \
    -l:libfile.a -l:libfilesearcher.a -l:libftpclient.a -l:libftplib.a -l:libdbclient.a -l:libsqlite3.a -l:libscheduler.a -l:libws2_32.a
SFTP_LDFLAGS= -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -s -L $(ROOT_DIR)/lib/Release -l:libboost_thread-mgw46-mt-1_49.a -l:libcommon.a \
    -l:libfile.a -l:libfilesearcher.a -l:libdbclient.a -l:libsqlite3.a -l:libscheduler.a -l:libsftpclient.a -l:libws2_32.a -l:libssh.dll

OBJECTS= appconfig.o backuplauncher.o clientbackup.o main.o
LD_OBJECTS= $(addprefix $(O_DIR)/,$(OBJECTS))

all: init $(TARGETS)

debug: CXXFLAGS= -O0 -g3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0
debug: BUILD_TYPE= Debug
debug: all

init:
    @mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    @mkdir -p $(O_DIR)

ftp_auto_backup: set_type_ftp $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CXX) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$@.exe $(LD_OBJECTS) $(FTP_LDFLAGS)

sftp_auto_backup: set_type_sftp $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$@.exe $(LD_OBJECTS) $(SFTP_LDFLAGS)

set_type_ftp:
    $(eval CXXFLAGS+=-DPROJECT_TYPE=FTP)

set_type_sftp:
    $(eval CXXFLAGS+=-DPROJECT_TYPE=SFTP)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $(O_DIR)/$@

clean:
    rm -rf $(addprefix $(ROOT_DIR)/Release/obj/,$(OBJECTS)) $(addprefix $(ROOT_DIR)/Debug/obj/,$(OBJECTS))
    rm -rf $(addprefix $(ROOT_DIR)/Release/,$(addsuffix .exe,$(TARGETS))) $(addprefix $(ROOT_DIR)/Debug/,$(addsuffix .exe,$(TARGETS)))
```

Yes, I know about [Generating Prerequisites Automatically](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Prerequisites), but should I really use it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no idea why you don't use the builtin targets. Moreover some of your phony targets, such as `all` and `debug` aren't marked as `.PHONY`.

Comment: Side-note: more than asking us about your immediate goal, you should perhaps tell us what it is you are trying to achieve overall? The make file contents are very ... uhm ... unorthodox, I'd say.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED What builtin targets do you mean? I don't use .PHONY, because I don't need it this time.
>> what it is you are trying to achieve overall?
I want to build two versions of application with different functional, but from same source files.
>> The make file contents are very ... uhm ... unorthodox, I'd say.
What does exactly makes you think that?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your targets depend on objects in the current directory, not in obj/. Change to this:

```
ftp_auto_backup: set_type_ftp $(LD_OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$@.exe $(LD_OBJECTS) $(FTP_LDFLAGS)

sftp_auto_backup: set_type_sftp $(LD_OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$@.exe $(LD_OBJECTS) $(SFTP_LDFLAGS)

# (...)

$(O_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

And yes, if you want your object files to recompile not only when you change the .cpp file, but also when you change the header (.h) files, you need to generate those prerequisites...

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed the situation! My mistake, really need to sleep now for a while)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that **%.o : %.cpp** is not enough, you should use VPATH to let know make where the sources are:

```
vpath %.cpp src
```